# MySQL Database represent folder structure most efficient way?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, nosql, schema

I would like to create a db schema to represent folder structures created by each user.

For example:

```
My Documents
 -- My Pictures
 -- My Videos
    -- Summer Holidays
```

So the most easiest way I could think about is just create a table named:

folder_structure
containing:

```
id,user_id,folder_name,parent_id,child_id
```

Thinking about that each user could create many folders this table would explode and I am not sure about the performance.

Is there any better way of storing this kind of data?
I was thinking about storing it document-based (nosql) maybe for each user...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Unless you expect several million entries, using this should be ok(and you can still limit the amount of folders someone is allowed to create). I just wonder what child_id is good for.

Comment: How many folders will each user have in average? I'm sure this structure is ok. Also i think that child_id field will not work because there are a lot of children in each folder.

Comment: @Rene Geuze I didn't read your question before I wrote mine :)

Comment: Hey thanks for your replies. There will be millions of entries :) Running on mysql galera cluster.

Comment: [This might be of help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree)

Comment: I can't see either a reason or a purpose for the `Child_ID` entry.